# Cakephp hasOne Model and hasAndBelongsToMany Model

Tags: php, cakephp, relationship, cakephp-model

I am having problems with the CakePHP belongsTo and hasAndBelongsToMany relationships in CakePHP 2.x

*Example situation*

Table **users**

```
id
organisation_id
```

Table **organisations**

```
id
name
```

Table **user_organisation_permissions**

```
id
user_id
organisation_id
```

UserModel

```
hasAndBelongsToMany(Organisation);
belongsTo(Organisation)
```

A user belongs to one organisation but it has permissions on multiple organisations, resulting in the following conflict:

```
$aUser = $this->User->findById(1);
print_r($aUser);

// Output

# With the belongsTo relation
array(
    'User' => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'organisation_id' => 1
        'name' => 'Test User'
    ),
    'Organisation' => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Test organisation'
    )
);

# With the hasAndBelongsToMany relation
array(
    'User' => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'organisation_id' => 1
        'name' => 'Test User'
    ),
    'Organisation' => array(
        1 => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Test organisation'
        ),
        2 => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Test organisation'
        )
    )
);

# When both relations are enabled it doesn't work
```

Does anybody have a solution for this conflict?

Is there a "native" CakePHP solution for this conflict?

Comment: What "conflict" are you referring to? ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: Ok, I added some more explanation.

Comment: I see, already suspected that: [**Cookbook > Models > Associations > Multiple relations to the same model**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#multiple-relations-to-the-same-model)

Comment: @ndm So in the first example they show, Sender & Recipient are like "Virtual" models?

Comment: Well, depending on what you mean by "virtual", you could probably call it something like that, though there's not really any virtualization going on, it's as virtual as storing a reference to an object in two variables with different names. `Sender` and `Recipient` are just aliases, which will be used instead of the actual model name.

Comment: Thank you sir! I didn't know this was actually in the cookbook :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually in the CakePHP 2.x Cookbook.

***Multiple relations to the same model***

*There are cases where a Model has more than one relation to another Model. For example, you might have a Message model that has two relations to the User model: one relation to the user who sends a message, and a second to the user who receives the message. The messages table will have a field user_id, but also a field recipient_id. Now your Message model can look something like:*

```
class Message extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Sender' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ),
        'Recipient' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'recipient_id'
        )
    );
}
```

Source: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#multiple-relations-to-the-same-model